# Testing google assistant using gactions CLI

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

For testing my assistant app, I want to use 'gactions CLI'(https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli)

But, When I try this part

```
$ gactions test --action_package PACKAGE_NAME --project PROJECT_ID
For example:
$ gactions test --action_package mypackage.json --project my-project-1234567
```

In this link(https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli)

I can't find what is the 'PACKAGE_NAME (mypackage.json)'.

How can I get my project's 'mypackage.json'???

Where is that file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PACKAGE_NAME` field in this case is your `actions.json` file, or whatever you have called the [Action definition package file](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/#create_actions_in_an_action_package). This is where you defined the entry point to your Action and describe how to access the fulfillment server.

Comment: If this helps, an upvote and/'or accepting the answer is always appreciated.